# How to colorize section headings in LaTeX like this?

Tags: colors, formatting, latex, heading

Accidently I created this nice colored effect on my LaTeX TOC:
http://i43.tinypic.com/o5aptl.png

Which I like and want to keep, I created this effect like this:

```
\definecolor{Section1}{rgb}{0.09,0.21,0.36}
\section{\color{Section1}Introdução}
```

However, as you can see on the TOC sidebar, there was a nasty side effect.

I tried to fix it like this:

```
\section[Introdução]{\color{Section1}Introdução}
```

But didn't work, the sidebar TOC was fixed but on the TOC list, the blue color was gone and was now red instead (default for clickable TOC heading links)

I also tried:

```
{\color{Section1}\section{Introdução}}
```

But the effect was the same, fixed TOC but no color on the TOC list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `\texorpdfstring{texString}{pdfString}`, which you can supply as an alternate to plaintext as an argument to `\section`. This should work:

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{\color{Section1}Intro}{Intro}}
```

Comment: It worked, but please change your example so that people realize that that should be placed inside \section{} which I didn't realize at first :P Thanks.